# Nativescript-Vue 7 - After creating a new project i cannot see network activity in the google chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I created the project using this command `vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template <project name>`

this is the command I used to debug `ns debug ios/android`

this used to work in the previous version out of the box

After researching, I found that this `domainDebugger.getNetwork()` returns undefined ( dont know if its the reason and if so how to fix it).

Its located here:  `node_modules/@nativescript/core/http/http-request/index.ios.js`

Added the current package JSON

```html
  "dependencies": {
    "vuex": "^3.5.1",
    "@vue/devtools": "^5.3.3",
    "nativescript-socketio": "^3.3.1",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "^1.4.0",
    "nativescript-toasty": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@nativescript/theme": "^2.3.3",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.8.1",
    "@nativescript/core": "^7.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@nativescript/ios": "7.0.6",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "^3.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.8.1",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.12.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is currently in progress and has been partially fix
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8966
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9058

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to this [tweet](https://twitter.com/NativeScript/status/1352692884038815744).

Must update dependencies and clean.

```
npm i @nativescript/ios
npm i @nativescript/core 
ns clean
```

Comment: ok so i tried it and it works on the android but the network still doesn't appear for ios.